# Does Tomcat 8 on Java 8 support applications built for Java 6 and Tomcat 6?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

My organization is migrating from a Java 6 / Tomcat 6 environment to a Java 8 / Tomcat 8 environment.

I would like to keep things simple on my development box by setting up as follows:

- Java 6 and Java 8 installed on the box.
- Java 8 as the default version of Java.
- Tomcat 8 as the application server, running on Java 8.
- Eclipse with two workspaces, one configured for Java 6 and one for Java 8, both deploying on the Tomcat 8 server.  The idea is to use the Java 6 workspace for maintenance work so that I can deploy on the old Java6/Tomcat6 server, and to use the Java 8 workspace for new and migrated work.

I would swear I did exactly this without thinking in my prior development box (that died of hardware failure) and that I experienced no problems at all, but I am not certain.

Is this a reasonable setup?

If it is supposed to work, is it because the application is working in a backward compatible mode?

Input would be greatly welcome.  I've been hunting all over the web unsuccessfully.  Thanks.

Comment: It would be weird if it weren't backwards-compatible. I am no expert, but I don't see why there would be any problems.

Comment: Hunt some more. There's plenty of information on the backwards compatibility of both Java and Tomcat, and if you can't find that information you shouldn't be touching either one of them.

Comment: Tomcat is a **complex** product; coming with a ton of features; and probably bugs, undocumented behavior here or there ... you name it. If you add several "reasonably sized aka complex" applications ... I would be rather surprised if you would **not** run into various smaller and bigger problems. There is a reason why updates in MAJOR release numbers typically ...

Comment: ... translate to: not a simple "migration" ahead of you. But the thing is: this very much depends on your applications, thus your question is way too broad. My recommendation: figure some more details on what your code is doing; and then look out for Tomcat users groups/forums. Ask those people that *give* you Tomcat.

Comment: Your asking the wrong question...the question is DOES my application support Java 8 and Tomcat 8.  I can say for a fact that in some cases depending on your applications dependencies that it will not work at all.  While it may run you may get very strange behaviour.   Our issue was we depended on jasperreports and due to the way Charsequence worked it caused a critical failure in the app under JAVA 8

Answer (score 0):

See the tomcat link for compatibility as follows :

http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

tomcat 8 on java 8 will definitely support applications built for java 6 and tomcat 6. I saw code where they are using a code from jdk 1.2 which runs on jdk 6 and tomcat 7.

Few exceptions would be some deprecated methods if you have used in earlier versions of java which will not be supported as it may be removed from newer version of java.

Also if you use third party libraries, you may need to maintain java version compatibility among them.

Otherwise it should work perfectly fine.